# Navbar with javascript css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having problems with my drop-down menu, I was watching a tutorial and I still can't get it to work and here's whats going on, the drop-down menu is not changing to white and it's not dropping down.

Also, when I resize my window to a mobile size, the navbar continues to follow, instead of fading as it does and is intended on a desktop size.

Here's the code:

```css
.menu-icon{
    width:100%;
    background: #000;
    text-align: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:none;
}

@media(max-width:580px){
    .logo{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        margin-top:16px;
    }
    .preheader ul{
        max-height:0px;
        background: #000;
    }
    .preheader.black ul{
        background: #000;
    }
    .showing{
        max-height: 20em;
    }
    .preheader ul li{
        box-sizing:border-box;
        width:100%;
        padding: 24px 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .menu-icon{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="preheader">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menu-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
    My logo
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Top</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".menu-icon").on("click", function(){
          $(".preheader ul").toggleClass("showing");
      });
    });

      $(window).on("scroll", function(){

        if($(window).scrollTop()){
          $('.preheader').addClass('black');
        }
        else{
          $('.preheader').removeClass('black');
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: You don't have any drop-down menu in there and you don't appear to have a Bootstrap navbar there either...

Comment: Sorry im just really tired, what i wanna do is drop the menu down when menu is clicked as it is supposed to do according to that js code, for some reason its not working

Answer (score 0):

plase this smaple this responsive

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {margin:0;}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem with my code is that it is supposed to to change the height to 350px so it can display the menu like a list and it should turn into a menu-icon again after i click it, changing the height to 0px; For some reason from what i noticed the jquery classes are not being called and i dont know why